# Moving by line and not by sentence

Tags: vim, macvim

Using macvim. Say I have one sentence which takes up 5 lines in the editor. And a second sentence which occupies the 5 next lines. Start with cursor on line 1. In normal mode, pressing `j` will take me to the next sentence (that is, line 6).

How to change this behavior to where pressing `j` will take me to line 2 (which is still part of the first sentence?). Or instead of using `j`, any other way to achieve this goal?

Comment: The line is what you call "sentence". `set nowrap` will show it as a line. I think, there is no way to do that, because the length of that "line" depends on the windows size, and there is no actual separator between that "lines".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem is that the line (not sentence) is too long and it wraps to multiple display lines. The default movement with `j` and `k` will move the cursor in real lines, not display lines.

You can remap `j` and `k` in normal mode to do move in display lines:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

(in your .vimrc).

Answer (score 3):

`j` takes you to the next line. I think you have a terminology problem (“sentence” doesn't mean what you seem to think it means). If `j` doesn't take you to the next line on the screen, it's because the file contains a very long line (what you call a “sentence”) that is too wide to fit on the screen. If there is a very long line, it is displayed on several screen lines. Vim calls these “**display lines**”. The `j` command moves to the same position on the next file line; **`gj`** moves to the same column on the next screen line.

Comment: While I think your explanation adds a lot of value, I think it would be far better to start with the solution: you can use `gj`. Now the simple answer is hidden in the tail of a long and (likely) confusing snake

Comment: Well, I was using the word "sentence" to give some context, but I know lines do not necessarily correspond to actual sentences. Didn't know the term for display lines. But thanks, this is what I was looking for.